# Как отредактировать языковой пакет?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Может кто-то знает как отредактировать языковой пакет в vscode, файл "ru.pak" хочу изменить перевод интерфейса.Возможно есть какие-то программы для этого, очень нужно изменить перевод.